# Callback hell in multiple if, else if statements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function with **data** and **callback** parameters. The **data** is an object with many attributes and I have to validate these. I wrote multiple if, else if statements to do it, but it seems so disgusting to me.

```
function(data, callback) {

 if (data.a != 'x') {
   logger.log(...);
   return callback({status: false, code: 'x'});
 } else if (data.b != 'y') {
   logger.log(...);
   return callback({status: false, code: 'y'});
 } else if (data.c != 'z') {
   logger.log(...);
   return callback({status: false, code: 'z'});
 } else if (data.d != 'w') {
   logger.log(...);
   return callback({status: false, code: 'w'});
 }

 //... logic ...
 return callback({status: true});
}
```

I think It's not the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: Maybe use a switch?

Comment: @zozo He's comparing different properties in each one, so `switch` is out.

Comment: It *seems* disgusting, but actually looks quite fine to me to be fair.

Comment: Do you have these comparisons defined somewhere?

Comment: @UselessCode You are right. How about making a function then, that returns status and code and make the whole cascade there. Then in the main function just callback with the returned result. Or use a try catch and throw exception with the code.

Comment: I see a pattern in there, is it really a pattern or just for the sake of this example?

Comment: Also the final callback is called no matter which `if` gets executed. Maybe there should be an `else` before it

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It's just an example. The real conditions are more complicated.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen You are right! I forget to wrote **return;**

Comment: May be you can use es6 new feature called "promise" instead

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of it but you could do [something like this](https://jsbin.com/fahetibozu/edit?html,js,console,output), just giving you options but I prefer georg's or BlazeSahlzen's answer better, for no other reason than they look 'cleaner'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to factor the validation into a separate function:

```
function failureCode(data) {
    if (data.a != 'x')
        return 'x';
    if (data.b != 'y')
        return 'y';
    if (data.c != 'z')
        return 'z';
}

function (data, callback) {
    var code = failureCode(data);
    if (code) {
        logger.log(...);
        return callback({status: false, code: code});
    }

    //... logic ...
}
```

Also, don't forget to `return` from the "failed" branch.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Since you are actually doing a validation and a "submission" you can just throw the codes and catch the result.

```
function(data, callback) {
    try {
         if (data.a != 'x') {
             throw 'x';
         }

         if (data.b != 'y') {
             throw 'y';
         }

         // etc

         // logic

         callback({status: true});
    }
    catch(code) {
        callback({status: false, code: code});
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there's a programming error within the try block?

Comment: Then the catch block should be come more complicated. But it would mean the way app is structured is wrong since from OP: "The data is an object with many attributes and I have to validate these". It is a validator function. Should be only basic comparisons here. This case is actually one of basic examples of "error" recovery with try catch.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems the code is correct but needs to be *pleasing to the eyes*, here's something you can try:

```
function(data, callback) {

  var code;

  if (data.a != 'x') code = 'x';
  else if (data.b != 'y') code = 'y';
  else if (data.c != 'z') code = 'z';
  else if (data.d != 'w') code = 'w';

  if (code) {
    callback({ status: false, code: code });
  } else {
    callback({ status: true });
  }
}
```

If the comparisons are known beforehand, then:

```
function(data, callback) {

  var code,

    comparisons = [{
      key: 'a',
      val: 'x'
    }, {
      key: 'b',
      val: 'y'
    }, {
      key: 'c',
      val: 'z'
    }, {
      key: 'd',
      val: 'w'
    }];

  for (each of comparisons) {

    if (data[each.key] != each.val) {
      code = each.val;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (code) {
    callback({ status: false, code: code });
  } else {
    callback({ status: true });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this because you're reading from different fields on data, and using inequalities. If you were reading from the same key on data (call it `code`), you could do the following in idiomatic javascript:

```
function (data, callback) {
  switch(data.code) {
      case 'x':
          logger.log(...);
          callback({status: false, code: 'x'});
          break;
      case 'y':
          logger.log(...);
          callback({status: false, code: 'y'});
          break;
      case 'z':
          logger.log(...);
          callback({status: false, code: 'z'});
          break;
      case 'w':
          logger.log(...);
          callback({status: false, code: 'w'});
          break;
      default:
          callback({status: true})
   }
}
```

Note that the switch statement is actually fairly distinct from your original functionality. First of all it is a truthy assertion on value, which results in only one branch every running. E.g. in your original code if data were an object like so:

`const data = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd'}` every branch would run, while in the switch implementation only the default branch would run. In either case, I would encourage you to rearchitect your solution for ease of reasoning into a shape that fits the switch.

If you are ok with using ES6 syntax/object destructuring, you could hook up your project with a transpiler like babel, and still use multiple keys like your original implementation, to do the following

```
function ({a, b, c, d}, callback) {
  if (a != 'x') {
    logger.log(...);
    callback({status: false, code: 'x'});
  } else if (b != 'y') {
    logger.log(...);
    callback({status: false, code: 'y'});
  } else if (c != 'z') {
    logger.log(...);
    callback({status: false, code: 'z'});
  } else if (d != 'w') {
    logger.log(...);
    callback({status: false, code: 'w'});
  }

  //... logic ...
  callback({status: true});
}
```

With a little bit more preconfiguration you could do something like:

```
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
const codes = {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z', 'd': 'w'}
```

Your function could now be:

```
function(data, callback) {
  keys.map(function(key) {
    if (data[key] != codes[key]) {
      logger.log(...);
      callback({status: false, code: codes[key]});
    }})
    //logic
    callback({status: true})
    }
```

note you could pass in the codemap / keylist as a function argument if you so wish

Answer (score 0):

I would include a set of expected values in my validation routine:

```
function(data, expected, callback) {
  var checkProp = function(prop) {
    return (data[prop] === expected[prop]);
  };

  for (var p in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      if (!checkProp(p)) {
        callback({status: false, code: expected[p]});
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  callback({status: true});
}
```

So, for example, if I had an object:

`{ a: 1, b: 2}`

I might include an `expected` parameter like this:

`{ a: 3, b: 4 }`

Here's a working demo:

```js
function validate(data, expected, callback) {
  var checkProp = function(prop) {
    return (data[prop] === expected[prop]);
  };

  for (var p in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      if (!checkProp(p)) {
        callback({status: false, code: expected[p]});
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  callback({status: true});
}

var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 },
  expected = { a: 1, b: 4 };
validate(obj, expected, function(res) {
  if (!res.status) {
    console.log('failed with value ' + res.code);
  } else {
    console.log('success');
  }
});
```